# How to parse the JSON Array value in C# (Windows phone 7)?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I'm working in WP7. I need to parse JSON array value in to list box. Somebody said, use Serializer and Deserializer but i dont know how to parse those values in to combo box or list box using serilizer and deserializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 string MyJsonString ="{your JSON here}"; //JSON Result
 var ds = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(City[]));
 var msnew = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyJsonString));
 City[] items = (City[])ds.ReadObject(msnew);
 foreach (var ev in items)
 {
   ComboCityBox.Items.Add((ev.name.ToString()));// binding name in to combobox
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) - I've used that with no problems in Windows Phone 7.

Don't focus on the list box to start with - focus on converting from JSON to your own type. Then separately deal with how to show a collection of objects of that type in your list box.

Comment: I use this too and I'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`. However, for improved performance you should consider using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/).

```
string jsonString = "{your JSON here}";

var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString));

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(YourListObject));

var deserialized = (YourListObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

You could then iterate over the items in your object and add them to the listbox.